# Cannot create service: service port not found when create treafik ingress route

Tags: kubernetes

When I am create treafik ingress,it throw this error:

```
{"ingress":"kubernetes-dashboard-route","level":"error","msg":"Cannot create service: service port not found","namespace":"kube-system","providerName":"kubernetescrd","serviceName":"kubernetes-dashboard","servicePort":8443,"time":"2020-01-30T18:12:15Z"}
{"ingress":"kubernetes-dashboard-route","level":"error","msg":"Cannot create service: service port not found","namespace":"kube-system","providerName":"kubernetescrd","serviceName":"kubernetes-dashboard","servicePort":8443,"time":"2020-01-30T18:12:17Z"}
```

this is the treafik define kubernetes-dashboard-route.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: traefik.containo.us/v1alpha1
kind: IngressRoute
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard-route
spec:
  entryPoints:
    - websecure
  tls:
    secretName: cloud-mydlq-tls
  routes:
    - match: Host(`kubernetes.balabala.com`)
      kind: Rule
      services:
        - name: kubernetes-dashboard
          port: 8443
```

this is the kubernetes dashboard file:

```
{
  "kind": "Pod",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {
    "name": "kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9",
    "generateName": "kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-",
    "namespace": "kube-system",
    "selfLink": "/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/pods/kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b-mrrs9",
    "uid": "fafd91a2-6e49-4f09-8479-b593f3f1d005",
    "resourceVersion": "12218565",
    "creationTimestamp": "2020-01-25T16:51:10Z",
    "labels": {
      "k8s-app": "kubernetes-dashboard",
      "pod-template-hash": "6466b68b"
    },
    "annotations": {
      "scheduler.alpha.kubernetes.io/critical-pod": "",
      "seccomp.security.alpha.kubernetes.io/pod": "docker/default"
    },
    "ownerReferences": [
      {
        "apiVersion": "apps/v1",
        "kind": "ReplicaSet",
        "name": "kubernetes-dashboard-6466b68b",
        "uid": "3d8e2739-5113-4398-b7b8-28bda186b15e",
        "controller": true,
        "blockOwnerDeletion": true
      }
    ]
  },
  "spec": {
    "volumes": [
      {
        "name": "kubernetes-dashboard-certs",
        "secret": {
          "secretName": "kubernetes-dashboard-certs",
          "defaultMode": 420
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "tmp-volume",
        "emptyDir": {}
      },
      {
        "name": "kubernetes-dashboard-token-pmxpf",
        "secret": {
          "secretName": "kubernetes-dashboard-token-pmxpf",
          "defaultMode": 420
        }
      }
    ],
    "containers": [
      {
        "name": "kubernetes-dashboard",
        "image": "gcr.azk8s.cn/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.1",
        "args": [
          "--auto-generate-certificates",
          "--token-ttl=43200"
        ],
        "ports": [
          {
            "containerPort": 8443,
            "protocol": "TCP"
          }
        ],
        "resources": {
          "limits": {
            "cpu": "100m",
            "memory": "300Mi"
          },
          "requests": {
            "cpu": "50m",
            "memory": "100Mi"
          }
        },
        "volumeMounts": [
          {
            "name": "kubernetes-dashboard-certs",
            "mountPath": "/certs"
          },
          {
            "name": "tmp-volume",
            "mountPath": "/tmp"
          },
          {
            "name": "kubernetes-dashboard-token-pmxpf",
            "readOnly": true,
            "mountPath": "/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount"
          }
        ],
        "livenessProbe": {
          "httpGet": {
            "path": "/",
            "port": 8443,
            "scheme": "HTTPS"
          },
          "initialDelaySeconds": 30,
          "timeoutSeconds": 30,
          "periodSeconds": 10,
          "successThreshold": 1,
          "failureThreshold": 3
        },
        "terminationMessagePath": "/dev/termination-log",
        "terminationMessagePolicy": "File",
        "imagePullPolicy": "IfNotPresent"
      }
    ],
    "restartPolicy": "Always",
    "terminationGracePeriodSeconds": 30,
    "dnsPolicy": "ClusterFirst",
    "serviceAccountName": "kubernetes-dashboard",
    "serviceAccount": "kubernetes-dashboard",
    "nodeName": "azshara-k8s01",
    "securityContext": {},
    "schedulerName": "default-scheduler",
    "tolerations": [
      {
        "key": "CriticalAddonsOnly",
        "operator": "Exists"
      },
      {
        "key": "node.kubernetes.io/not-ready",
        "operator": "Exists",
        "effect": "NoExecute",
        "tolerationSeconds": 360
      },
      {
        "key": "node.kubernetes.io/unreachable",
        "operator": "Exists",
        "effect": "NoExecute",
        "tolerationSeconds": 360
      }
    ],
    "priorityClassName": "system-cluster-critical",
    "priority": 2000000000,
    "enableServiceLinks": true
  },
  "status": {
    "phase": "Running",
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "Initialized",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2020-01-25T16:51:10Z"
      },
      {
        "type": "Ready",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2020-01-25T16:51:24Z"
      },
      {
        "type": "ContainersReady",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2020-01-25T16:51:24Z"
      },
      {
        "type": "PodScheduled",
        "status": "True",
        "lastProbeTime": null,
        "lastTransitionTime": "2020-01-25T16:51:10Z"
      }
    ],
    "hostIP": "172.19.104.231",
    "podIP": "172.30.224.9",
    "startTime": "2020-01-25T16:51:10Z",
    "containerStatuses": [
      {
        "name": "kubernetes-dashboard",
        "state": {
          "running": {
            "startedAt": "2020-01-25T16:51:23Z"
          }
        },
        "lastState": {},
        "ready": true,
        "restartCount": 0,
        "image": "gcr.azk8s.cn/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.1",
        "imageID": "docker-pullable://gcr.azk8s.cn/google_containers/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64@sha256:0ae6b69432e78069c5ce2bcde0fe409c5c4d6f0f4d9cd50a17974fea38898747",
        "containerID": "docker://07ab8a9e93cb2f9a27194f73094ce77cb8938edf32a36fe6962737bfd16c3c38"
      }
    ],
    "qosClass": "Burstable"
  }
}
```

what is wrong with my config,the kubernetes dashboard config is in 8443 port? and in the same namespace,why it give port not found exception?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The port 8443 is container port,could not access outside the container.You should using this command to find the cluster service port:

```
kubectl get svc --namespace=kube-system

NAME                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                   AGE
kube-dns               ClusterIP   10.254.0.2      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP    131d
kubernetes-dashboard   NodePort    10.254.75.193   <none>        443:31085/TCP             131d
traefik                ClusterIP   10.254.169.66   <none>        80/TCP,443/TCP,8080/TCP   2d4h
```

the port 443 is the cluster port treafik could access. change container port 8443 to port 443.